# Starting SVG animation using javascript "onload"

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, onload

I have some SVG animation code, but often when I open my website, the animation starts while it's loading, and not in it's full form.

```js
let refreshRate = Math.random() *1000 + 50; // 10 times per second
function rand(max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max+1));
}
setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("RectElement").setAttribute("fill","rgb("+rand(255)+", "+rand(255)+", "+rand(255)+")");},refreshRate);
```

```html
<!--start animation-->

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="8cm" height="3cm" viewBox="0 0 800 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <desc>Example anim01 - demonstrate animation elements</desc>
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="900" height="400"
        fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="2" />
  <!-- The following illustrates the use of the 'animate' element
        to animate a rectangles x, y, and width attributes so that
        the rectangle grows to ultimately fill the viewport. -->
  <rect id="RectElement" x="300" y="100" width="300" height="100"
        fill="rgb(0,255,0)"  >
    <animate attributeName="fill" begin="0" dur="1.3"
   repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="x" begin="0s" dur="1.3s"
             fill="freeze" from="300" to="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="y" begin="0s" dur="1.3s"
             fill="freeze" from="100" to="0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="width" begin="0s" dur="1.3s"
             fill="freeze" from="300" to="800" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="height" begin="0s" dur="1.3s"
             fill="freeze" from="100" to="300" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    
    
  </rect>
  <!-- Set up a new user coordinate system so that
        the text string's origin is at (0,0), allowing
        rotation and scale relative to the new origin -->
  <g transform="translate(100,100)" >
    <!-- The following illustrates the use of the 'set', 'animateMotion',
         'animate' and 'animateTransform' elements. The 'text' element
         below starts off hidden (i.e., invisible). At 3 seconds, it:
           * becomes visible
           * continuously moves diagonally across the viewport
           * changes color from blue to dark red
           * rotates from -30 to zero degrees
           * scales by a factor of three. -->
    <text id="TextElement" x="0" y="0"
          font-family="Verdana" font-size="35.27" visibility="hidden"  >
      Buy our crap!
      <set attributeName="visibility" to="visible"
           begin="0s" dur="1.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      <animateMotion path="M 0 0 L 100 100"
           begin="0s" dur="1.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
           type="rotate" from="-30" to="0"
           begin="0s" dur="1.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
           type="scale" from="0.5" to="2" additive="sum"
           begin="0s" dur="1.3s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

What happens often when I open the page is that the box stays at it's smallest size and shifts colors very rapidly until the page fully loads, when it finally starts normally. However this causes the website to load extremely slowly. Is there any way (using JS), to make the animation only start once the page has fully loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code in a function and call it when the document is loaded with this syntax:

```
function rand(max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max+1));
}

function init() {
  let refreshRate = Math.random() *1000 + 50; // 10 times per second
  setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("RectElement").setAttribute("fill","rgb("+rand(255)+", "+rand(255)+", "+rand(255)+")");},refreshRate);
}

window.document.onload = init;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I think this will work, but I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: That's almost there. The square still appears while it's loading, and I want it to only appear once it has fully loaded.